# jquery put value to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script

---

```
<script>
    function trigger(){
    var x = document.getElementById('xcoord');
    var y = document.getElementById('ycoord');
    var box = document.getElementById('touch');

    if (x.value >= 325 || x.value <= 300 && y.value >= 55 || y.value <= 25) {
    $('#touch').value('passed');

    }

    }  
</script>
```

---

here is the html

---

```
 <input onchange="trigger()" required type="number" id="xcoord" name="xcoord">
 <input onchange="trigger()" required type="number" id="ycoord" name="ycoord">
 <input required type="text" id="touch" name="touch">
```

---

**i need a value to be displayed everytime the value of the xcoord and ycoord suits the condition, but no value is printed even the condition is true.**

Comment: `(x.value >= 325 || x.value <= 300) && (y.value >= 55 || y.value <= 25)`

Comment: okay, but still no value is printed

Comment: please replace the 'value()'  to val() in the  "$('#touch').value('passed');" line

Comment: I think you need to change value() to val()

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahfzr0af/#&togetherjs=mGjbrUA0kn this fiddle will help, have replaced some abitilies with jquery (on change of jquery instead of onchange)

Comment: i've replaced it to val() but still no printed value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed plain `JavaScript`with `JQuery`.

**Put value to input box with JavaScript**

```
box.value = 'passed';
```

*CodeSnippet*

```js
function trigger(){
    var x = document.getElementById('xcoord');
    var y = document.getElementById('ycoord');
    var box = document.getElementById('touch');

    if (x.value >= 325 || x.value <= 300 && y.value >= 55 || y.value <= 25) {
         box.value = 'passed';
    }
}
```

```html
<input onchange="trigger()" required type="number" id="xcoord" name="xcoord">
 <input onchange="trigger()" required type="number" id="ycoord" name="ycoord">
 <input required type="text" id="touch" name="touch">
```

**Put value to input box with JQuery**

```
$('#touch').val('passed'); //Although you already have the box variable
```

*CodeSnippet*

```js
 function trigger(){
    var x = document.getElementById('xcoord');
    var y = document.getElementById('ycoord');
    var box = document.getElementById('touch');

    if (x.value >= 325 || x.value <= 300 && y.value >= 55 || y.value <= 25) {
        $('#touch').val('passed');
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onchange="trigger()" required type="number" id="xcoord" name="xcoord">
 <input onchange="trigger()" required type="number" id="ycoord" name="ycoord">
 <input required type="text" id="touch" name="touch">
```

**tl;dr;**

Since you started code with plain `JavaScript`you confused how to change the value with `jQuery`syntax.

**JavaScript** `box.value = 'passed';`

**jQuery** `$('#touch').val('passed');`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the jQuery Library. Use better than **jQuery** methods.

```js
$("#xcoord , #ycoord").on("keyup",  function(){
    var x = $('#xcoord').val();
    var y = $('#ycoord').val();
   $('#touch').val((x >= 325 || x <= 300) && (y >= 55 || y <= 25)?'passed':'');
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required type="number" id="xcoord" name="xcoord" value="0">
 <input  required type="number" id="ycoord" name="ycoord" value="0">
 <input required type="text" id="touch" name="touch">
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
 $('#touch').val('passed');
```